# Filter one row from the middle of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

I have a data frame with dimensions (21,10).  I don't want the 18th row. So I've been trying to filter it out by:

```
filtered_data_frame <- original_data_frame[1:17+19:21,]
```

but the '+' is obviously the wrong character to use here.  What should I use instead?  I've tried `,.|:;` etc!

Comment: I don't know what tags are sorry.  I'm new to R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it a couple of ways.  The easiest is to just take out the row you **don't** want, the 18th row.  It's the same as taking `18` out of the sequence from 1 to 21.

```
> c(1:21)[-18]
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 21
```

So on the data frame, you can remove the 18th row with `original_data_frame[-18, ]`.

Or, you can do it the other way by taking the rows you **do** want

```
> c(1:17, 19:21)
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 21
```

which would be `original_data_frame[c(1:17, 19:21), ]`